# NSDictionary to Json in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I am trying to convert the `NSDictionary` into `Json` using `NSJsonSerialization.Serialize`. But i am not getting expected output

**Code in Xamarin.iOS**

```
var dictionary = new NSDictionary(
                new NSString("userName"), new NSString("450012"),
                new NSString("password"), new NSString("Abc134"),
                new NSString("companyId"), new NSString("CM1")
            );

request.Body = NSJsonSerialization.Serialize(dictionary, 0, out error);
```

the problem is that value of `dictionary` variable is showing

> {{password":Abc134,companyId:CM1,userName:450012}}

instead of

> {password:Abc134,companyId:CM1,userName:450012}

it is adding one curly braces at the front and back

is there any way to generate proper json string for user input values

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with your json. If you print it in the console you will see that the value being printed is the value you expect.

`{"password":"Abc134","companyId":"CM1","userName":"450012"}`

Give it a try with:

`Console.WriteLine($"{json}");`

If you really, really want to get rid of of that "extra" curly braces just convert the result into string.

`var jsonString = json.ToString();`

The above should do the work.

I would just suggest you changing your method to this:
`var json2 = NSJsonSerialization.Serialize(dictionary, NSJsonWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, out error);`

Using the [PrettyPrinted](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization/writingoptions/1418364-prettyprinted) option.

Hope this helps.-

Comment: All i am trying to pass the json string into `requset.Body` and `request.Body` does take `NSData` as an argument hence i used `NSJsonSerialization` but the problem is `NSJsonSerialization` does access its first argument as `NSObject` so how can i convert my `{"password":"Abc134","companyId":"CM1","userName":"450012"}` to NSObject os that `NSJsonSerialization` can accept it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try to create a custom object to serialize. Create a simple plain object to hold the data you want.

```
User user = new User() {
    UserName = "JohnDoe",
    Password = "xxx",
    CompanyId = 01
};
request.Body = NSJsonSerialization.Serialize(user, 0, out error);
```

Then serialize it and you will see the proper json well formed.

Comment: this does not work as you can not convert xamarin `User` object to `NSObject`.